# What does »Mein neuer Alpi <3« mean?

Tags: german-to-english

The *taz.de* article “[Je gefährlicher, desto mehr Klicks](http://taz.de/YouTube-foerdert-die-Raserei/!5371411/)” is about motorcycle vloggers (video bloggers) who post their videos on Youtube. One of these vloggers is *Blackout*, who has recently uploaded a video of himself riding a motorcycle with a speed of almost 300 km/h. *Alpi fährt* is another vlogger guilty of having recently killed a pedestrian with his motorcycle.

The article ends with the following two paragraphs:

> Noch rasanter als Blackout fuhr der Bremer Moto-Vlogger „Alpi fährt“. Nachdem er bei einer Fahrt mit über 100 km/h innerorts einen 75-Jährigen totgefahren hatte, stellte er seinen Kanal mit rund 85.000 Abonnenten auf privat. Im Monat vor der Tat verdiente er mit Youtube 900 Euro.
>
> Unter Blackouts Videos stehen oft Kommentare wie: „**Mein neuer Alpi
>   <3**.“ Blackout sagt in einem seiner Videos dazu: „Ihr könnt das gerne
>   schreiben. Aber ihr sollt wissen, dass es nicht so ist. Und dass ich
>   das auch ein bisschen als Kompliment sehe.“ Über Alpis Unfall will er
>   nicht reden, dafür aber über dessen Videos, die eine Grundlage für die
>   Mordanklage waren: „Seine Videos haben mir gefallen. Er war ein cooler
>   Typ, **vom Menschlichen**.“

I don't understand what *Mein neuer Alpi <3* mean. *Alpi* is obviously the moniker of that other vlogger who has killed a pedestrian. *My new Alpi is less than 3* makes no sense to me.

Also, what does *vom Menschlichen* mean? Is it something like *a humane one* ("He was a cool guy, a humane one" or "He was a cool and humane guy.")?

Comment: Actually, from reading the text I get the impression that *Alpi* is the original, the blueprint, and *Blackout* is the not-quite-as-cool runner-up, second, or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<3 Is a "standard internet smiley". Turn your monitor 90° counter-clockwise and it's supposed to be a heart. (You can also turn your head, but that is considered unhealthy)

> Mein neuer Alpi

would mean "he replaced Alpi for me"

> Er war ein cooler Typ, vom Menschlichen

Is not what you would call a proper German sentence.

> Er war ein cooler Typ, vom Menschlichen *her*

would be a bit better and roughly translate to "he was a cool buddy, from his human aspect" (whatever *that* would mean in this context.)

Comment: +1 für die Gesundheitswarnung! =D

Comment: @Jan Man will ja nicht, dass sich womöglich noch einer verletzt.

Answer (score 3):

The character sequence *<3* is a [smiley that stands for a heart](http://www.greensmilies.com/smilie-lexikon/#spitzklammerli). Turn your head by 90 degree and you should be able to see it.

So the writer of this comment wanted to say that Blackout now takes the place of Alpi for him and that he has whatever kind of positive emotion for him.